# Image not show in browser with Lumen Api

Tags: laravel, lumen

I use Lumen to get images and show in browser, my code in controller is :

```
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

    $photo = $this->uploadFile->get_by_photo($photo, ['filename']);
    $path = storage_path('app') . '/' . $photo[0]['filename'];
    $file = File::get($path);
    $type = File::mimeType($path);
    $response = response()->make($file, 200);
    $response->header("Content-Type", $type);
    return $response;
```

But image not show in browser , i just got a dark page when run that api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this code works:

```
    $photo = $this->uploadFile->get_by_photo($photo, ['filename']);
    $path = storage_path('app') . '/' . $photo[0]['filename'];
    $type = File::mimeType($path);
    $headers = array('Content-Type' => $type);
    $response = response()->download($path, $photo, $headers);
    ob_end_clean();
    return $response;
```